# jQuery select id working with string but not working with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, select

I wanted to make a script that will read the supplier name of each line and selecting the option what contains the same string.

I can not figure out why the last two lines of my the jQuery script are behaving differently.

The last line is working (Selecting the right option with [Supplier2] name) but only if I give the id as a string.

The commented out line is not working even if  I give the same string to the id as a variable. Any ideas why is that?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/josephturi/eu63a8yL/1/)

```js
$('#cart_table > tbody  > tr').each(function(i) {
    var actual_supplier = "[" + $(this).find(".actual_supplier").text() + "]";
    var item_id = $('select').attr('id');
    alert(item_id); // printed item_id looks like the same as id=supplier-selection-254
    console.log(i, actual_supplier, "id=",item_id);

// ------------------------- This is not working:

    //$('select[id=item_id] option:contains("[Supplier2]")').prop('selected',true); // This line should do the job but somehow not working with the same id name

// ------------------------- This is working:

    $('select[id=supplier-selection-254] option:contains("[Supplier2]")').prop('selected',true); // This line looks the same as line above it above

});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
<table id="cart_table" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Supplier</th>
            <th>Item</th>
          </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
          <td class="actual_supplier hidden">[Supplier2]</td>  
          <td><div>      
            <form id='change-supplier-form' method='GET' action=".">
              <select id=supplier-selection-254 name='item' class='form-control supplier_select'>
              <option  value = "Car1">Car 1 - [Supplier1]</option>
              <option  value = "Car2">Car 2 - [Supplier2]</option>
              <option  value = "Car3">Car 3 - [Supplier3]</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div></td>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: `'select[id=item_id]` is using the item_id as a literal string.  You have to concatenate in the variable like usual to use it's actual value.

Comment: How do you concatenate two strings (hint: see `actual_supplier`)?

Comment: `$("select[id=" + item_id + "]");`

Comment: Your code literally doesn't make sense.  [Select Html Element does not have a `selected` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

Comment: Thanks for the help, the missing quotes were the solution. Erik, you are right. Select Html element has no selected property.  Changed $('select[id=item_id] option:contains("[Supplier2]")') to  $("#" + item_id + " option:contains("[Supplier2]")')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the quotes.

```
 $( "select[id='" + item_id + "']" );
```